# Check if dynamically added class exists

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').length) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

This works if `<div class="myclass">...</div>` is directly written in the HTML document, but not if it's inserted by JavaScript itself. Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine your issue is because the class gets added *after* your `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired.

Answer (score 3):

Well, think about what you're doing with the listener. You're having this code run when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires. If you're changing the DOM in other places, there's no guarantee that this code will be run afterwards. In fact, unless you're manually emitting that event, [it seems like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) it would only ever run once per page.

However, since I don't know what the code looks like which is attaching classes at run-time, I can't be more specific.

As an example, the following code produces 'dom loaded', but not 'class is found!':

```
document.getElementById("foo").className = "myclass";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  alert('dom loaded');

    if (document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').length) {
       alert('My class is found!');
    }
});
```

And the following code produces both as expected.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  alert('dom loaded');

  document.getElementById("foo").className = "myclass";

    if (document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').length) {
       alert('My class is found!');
    }
});
```

To show you what I mean, here are plunkr links:

[working](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ec1Q8mMP71tBeYpWhXBW?p=preview)

[not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/K02cX11gn9r5cvk60r4R?p=info)

Comment: Thank you! What, if not only the class is added dynamically, but even the div element?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue as long as your function is being called at the right time. Just remember that 'DOMContentLoaded' is emitted when you load the page. If you want to grab a bunch of stuff you add afterwards, you'll need to use a different event listener, or otherwise invoke the function some other way.

EDIT: TLDR: getElementsByClassName doesn't care where something comes from, if it's on the DOM it will find it. It just needs to be invoked at the right time.

Comment: Which alternative event listener would you suggest?

Comment: Well, that depends on the use case. If you're adding the class in response to a click you could just add it to the click event. If it could happen at any time you could attach it to an interval. If you want to check in multiple locations you can declare the function seperately and simply pass it to multiple listeners... Javascript is full of possibilities :P

Answer (score 0):

Use `className.indexOf`

```
myElement = document.getElementById("IdOfTheElement");

if(myElement.className.indexOf('MyClassName') != -1){
   /* The class exist*/
}
```

Comment: Is an object: you can retrieve it by getElementById or similar

Comment: Assuming he wants to pull the objects by class, as the question suggests, this does not help him very much.

Comment: I don't understood correctly his question. You're right. x_X.
Sorry.